# Apollo/React - Slow initial request overrides data returned from quicker subsequent request

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm building a React app with Apollo Client to make GraphQL requests. I have a grid and some filters that load their values dynamically. On the initial page load, an unfiltered request occurs, which is slow. When the filters load their values, they set the first values as defaults. This triggers a subsequent filtered request for data, which is much quicker.

The issue I'm facing is that although the data from the second request is correctly displayed, the data from the slow initial request seems to override the data from the second request after it finishes.

I would expect the most recent request's data to always be the one returned and displayed. I wouldn't have thought that I need to handle this manually by cancelling requests.

Is there a way to ensure that the data from the most recent request is always displayed, regardless of the order in which the requests are resolved? I need the user to be able to choose to see all data if necessary, so requesting data only when filters are set is not an option.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!